# Constructing a dataset based on column data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that looks like :

```
ID        I_Code  Date_2     Date_1     c_b Count
FT-56832    2   01/09/2019  02/08/2019  1000 6  
FT-93828    1   01/09/2019  03/08/2019  44  31
FT-13853    2   02/09/2019  03/08/2019  79  31
FT-18858    3   02/09/2019  04/08/2019  30  47
FT-56832    2   01/09/2019  04/08/2019  35  47
FT-19010    2   03/09/2019  04/08/2019  53  47
FT-62064    5   02/09/2019  04/08/2019  79  47
FT-94494    4   03/09/2019  04/08/2019  96  47
FT-73594    2   03/09/2019  04/08/2019  89  47
FT-78590    1   01/09/2019  05/08/2019  66  30
FT-14296    4   01/09/2019  05/08/2019  20  30
FT-82529    3   03/09/2019  05/08/2019  95  30
FT-33266    3   04/09/2019  05/08/2019  80  30
FT-62064    5   02/09/2019  05/08/2019  80  30
FT-94494    4   03/09/2019  05/08/2019  97  30
```

I want to expand the dataset in such a way that the total entries in the dataset corresponds to the count column, for example for (Date_1, Date_2, ID, I_Code) there is a count and that count represents number of rows, like the first row should expand to 31 entries where we need to create   another column c_b1 and summation for c_b1 should be equal to c_b i.e. 34 in the case of example.

Thanks to @jezrael,

I was able to randomly divide it using the following code :

```
from numpy.random import multinomial 
def func(x): 
N = np.random.randint(5, 10, size=1)[0] 
print (N) 
return multinomial(x, [1./N] * N) 


a = df.join(pd.concat({k: pd.Series(func(v)) for k, v in df['value'].items()}).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('A')) 
print (a)
```

where the function v was generating the count. Now I already have the count and tries using this :

```
a = df.join(pd.concat({k: pd.Series(df['count']) for k, v in df['value'].items()}).reset_index(level=1, drop=True).rename('A')) 
    print (a)
```

but this is not providing the output.

Example of expected output :

**Expected Input :**

```
ID          I_code  date_1      date_2     value count 
FT-56832    2       01/09/2019  02/08/2019 1000  6
```

**Expected Output :**

```
 ID          I_code     date_1      date_2      c_b1   c_b
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     155    1000
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     170    1000
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     165    1000
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     174    1000
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     175    1000
    FT-56832    2         1/09/2019    2/08/2019     161    1000
```

Note that there is no contraint on distribution of the c_b1, it can be randomized.

Can anyone help with the same.

Thanks

Comment: Why do date_1 and date_2 change in the expanded rows?

Comment: @ScottBoston My apologies, the dates need to remain same, I was just providing the example

Comment: @ScottBoston I edited the example, can you take a look now?

Comment: does there need to be a distribution, will taking value and dividing by number of rows work?  So, equal distribution?

Comment: @ScottBoston distribution is not required but randommness, I don't want equal distibutions, any random distribution would do

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,  Try this:

```
def f(x):
    i = np.random.random(len(x))
    j = i/sum(i) * x
    return j

df1 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df['count']))
df1['value'] = df1.groupby('ID')['value'].transform(f)
print(df1)
```

Input:

```
ID          I_code  date_1      date_2     value count 
FT-56832    2       01/09/2019  02/08/2019 1000  6
FT-56831    3       01/09/2019  02/08/2019 500   4
```

Output:

```
         ID  I_code      date_1      date_2       value  count
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019   94.921398      6
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  317.340230      6
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  289.495352      6
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  135.989723      6
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  146.207420      6
0  FT-56832       2  01/09/2019  02/08/2019   16.045878      6
1  FT-56831       3  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  125.931392      4
1  FT-56831       3  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  147.763965      4
1  FT-56831       3  01/09/2019  02/08/2019  158.801276      4
1  FT-56831       3  01/09/2019  02/08/2019   67.503367      4
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little bit, I wanted to understand the function.

Comment: Okay df.index gets the index and repeat takes a integer so for the first record, repeat the index 0 six times.   Now, using re-index, we can repeat that first two six times.   Next, call a custom function for each group, where the group is the original index.    Generate a random value equal to the size of the group, divide by sum of those random generate numbers to obtain fractions of 1.   Multiply the value of X to get random fraction of X.

Comment: Okay, another thing that is a problem here is that, the count here represents for each date_2, now consider the second and third entry in the first dataframe shared. you see that for 03/08/2019, count is 31 in both the cases. I also want to distribute the count with respect to date_2 and date_1 and ID. so in this case, it doesnt mean that 31 entries for both but 31 entries combined for both.

Comment: for more explanation, let me take example for date_2 to be 04/08/2019. The count is referred to be 47. that means that for all 6 entries, the total count needs to be 47.

Comment: Can you edit the answer on that basis, if possible.

Comment: I want to set the minimm value to be taken as 10 in the column value, However, I am seeing values as 0 as well. Can you please edit your answer to take the minimum value as 10.

Comment: @dper, I am sorry I don't understand your new request.